# Triangle in sub-menu overlaps main menu-item

Tags: html, css, wordpress, menu

I added a decorative triangle using a `:before` on the sub-menu class. However, it covers its own main menu-item.

The website is not live yet, but I hope my screenshots will make the situation clear enough.

---

### [image]

This is what the menu looks like. It's a WordPress installation, with a basic navigation, nothing custom except the triangle.

---

### [image]

This is what I see when I hover on the `:before` inside of Chrome's inspector. It covers the bottom half of the main menu-item, making the bottom half unclickable.

---

### [image]

This is what it looks like when I give it a fixed `height` of `10px`. As you can see the triangle is centered, but the highlighted part begins above it.

---

Here's my code:

**menu-item**

```
position: relative;
float: left;
z-index: 999999;
```

**sub-menu**

```
text-align: center;
width: auto;
color: #78A22F;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
z-index: 2;
```

**sub-menu:before**

```
content: "\f0d8";
font-family: FontAwesome;
font-size: 40px;
position: absolute;
top: -36px;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
color: #78A22F;
line-height: 0px;
z-index: 2;
```

Does anyone have a fix or an alternative way to be able to use this triangle?

EDIT:
Here's a jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/48omajxx/1/

Comment: create a JSfiddle demo..

Comment: Have you tried giving the :before a `z-index:-1;`

Comment: @ Sanjeev K   I've added a jsFiddle demo. It doesn't look remotely close to the navigation in the screenshots, but it has the same functionality.

@Paul Yes, I've tried a negative z-index too, but without success

Comment: .sub-menu:before {pointer-events:none} it's certainly not the most elegant way but more like a quick fix.

Comment: @Paul  This is exactly what I needed... Thanks! (if you want, you can post this again as answer instead of comment, so I can upvote it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**CSS**

```
.sub-menu:before {
    /* Your other css properties */
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

**Note**
If there is a click event listener on the element. It will respect the pointer-events value and does not fire.

Interesting articles about pointer events:

- [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/pointer-events/)
- [Developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)